# unreachable statement calling for recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

Writing this code, I'm getting 'unreachable statement' error when I try to compile, any time I try to reach a[x] in the recursive method.

```
public class recursion
{
public static boolean match (int [] a, int [] pattern)
{
    if(pattern.length==0)
        return true;
    boolean x;
    x=match(a,pattern,0,0);
    if(x==true)
        return true;
    return false;

}

public static boolean match (int [] a, int [] pattern,int aCounter,int ptCounter)
    {
        int count=0;
        int x=aCounter;
        if(x==a.length);
        {
            if(count==pattern.length)
                return true;
            else return false;
        }

        if(a[x]>100)
        {
            count=0;
        return match(a,pattern,aCounter+1,0);
    }
    else if(((pattern[ptCounter]==1)||(pattern[ptCounter]==0))&&((a[x]>-10)&&(a[x]<10)))
    {
        count++;
        return match(a,pattern,aCounter+1,ptCounter+1);
    }
    else if(((pattern[ptCounter]==2)||(pattern[ptCounter]==0))&&(((a[x]<-10)&&(a[x]>-100))||((a[x]>9)&&(a[x]<100))))
    {   
        count++;
        return match(a,pattern,aCounter+1,ptCounter+1);
    }

}

}
```

Would appreciate input regarding this issue and also about the calling of recursive method. Thank you!

Comment: Not an answer, but just an observation: Instead of `if (condition) return true; else return false;` you should just do `return condition`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is an unnecessary `;` :

```
    if(x==a.length); // here
    {
        if(count==pattern.length)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

This `;` closes the if statement, so the following bock is always executed (and returns `true` or `false`), and the code after that block becomes unreachable.